# Session and Authentication Timeout don't work

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, iis, session-timeout

I set Sessionstate an Authentication Timeout in web.Config like below , but users are logout less than 20 minutes

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" name="Login" timeout="43200" slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>

<sessionState timeout="43200"></sessionState>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would like to clarify that Authentication has very little to do with Session.

Every time a new user hits the website the session starts.

And the amount of time that the authentication cookie is good for on the user's browser is defined by authentication time out.

You can also try to set the Session timeout by Going to IIS and setting Session timeout there as well

Comment: My site is in a share host and i cant Config the iis

Answer (score 0):

You should disable or increase the application pool timeout in IIS - web site properties.

Regards

Comment: My site is in a share host and i cant Config the iis